# save an arrayList of strings (hibernate) and display it in jsp

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

How can we display a list of string arrays in JSP?

This list is an attribute in a Java bean (USER) stored in the database using the Hibernate framework, this attribute become a blob after saving it in the database, and using the Spring framework, I send a list of users and I iterated over this list, so I have to display my `ArrayList` of strings in this list of users.

Comment: find how to iterate arraylist in jsp in google

Comment: the problème is not about iterating the arraylist in jsp it's simple ;getting the arraylist as string from the data base is the problème ,and without forget that i sent a list of users and for each user there is a Arraylist of strings

Comment: You say it's stored as a BLOB.  So it's a serialized Java object?  If so, deserialize it into a List object after hibernate fetches it from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Spring controller :`model.addAttribute("listUser", servicesU.getAllUsers());
return "User/listUser";`

in JSP :pathAcces is the attribute (my ArrayList)                                            `<tbody>
                                    <s:forEach items="${listUser}" var="user" >
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center">${user.nameUser}</td>

                                            <s:forEach items="${user.pathAcces}" var="path">

                                                <td>${path}</td>
                                              </s:forEach>

                                        </tr>
                                    </s:forEach>
                                </tbody>`